# CALayer Animation Scale with fixed centre on iOS7

Tags: ios, calayer, uiviewanimation

I've been banging my head over what I thought would have been an easy thing. A pulsing circle, there are several example on SO, but I'm still unable to fix one last thing.

With the code below, I do have a circle that expand and contracts fine, but during contraction, the scaling is done from the CGRect's layer frame (upper left corner). Expansion works fine, and both expansion/contraction work fine on iOS8. The problem only happens on iOS7.

I tried with setting the anchor point, translating the view while expanding ... nothing seemed to do the trick... I'm doing something wrong, I don't know what.

If anyone want to try with the code below you just need a UIViewController, a label, and a button, wired to the IBOutlets below.

That's my last - known - bug before I can submit my app to the app Store... :\

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end




#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isExpanded;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.isExpanded = YES;
    self.label.layer.cornerRadius = self.label.frame.size.width/2;
    self.label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
- (IBAction)ExpandOrCollapse:(id)sender {
    [self.button setEnabled:NO];
    CGFloat animationDuration = 0.30f; // Your duration
    CGFloat animationDelay = 0.0f; // Your delay (if any)

    if (self.isExpanded) {

       CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.17f, .17f);

        CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        scaleAnimation.duration = animationDuration;
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

        scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.17f];

        [self.label.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                              delay:animationDelay
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.isExpanded = NO;
                             [self.label setTransform:t];
                             [self.button setEnabled:YES];
                         }];
    }else{

        CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        scaleAnimation.duration = animationDuration;

        scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.17f];

        scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

        [self.label.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self.button setEnabled:YES];
                             [self.label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0f)];
                             self.isExpanded = YES;
                         }];
    }
}
@end
```

**EDIT**

for eiran, here's the code with his modifications. Problem is still present unfortunately..

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isExpanded;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.isExpanded = YES;
    self.label.layer.cornerRadius = self.label.frame.size.width/2;
    self.label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
- (IBAction)ExpandOrCollapse:(id)sender {
    [self.button setEnabled:NO];
    CGFloat animationDuration = 0.30f; // Your duration
    CGFloat animationDelay = 0.0f; // Your delay (if any)

    if (self.isExpanded) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                              delay:animationDelay
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             [self.label setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.17f, 0.17f)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.isExpanded = NO;
                             [self.button setEnabled:YES];
                         }];
    }else{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             [self.label setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0f, 1.0f)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self.button setEnabled:YES];

                             self.isExpanded = YES;
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: reset the center of the circle view in your animation block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.95, 0.95);
                 }completion:^(BOOL b){
                 }];
```

that's a repeating scale animation.

EDIT:
OK then:) apple works in mysterious ways.
i've found a solution for you, but i'm not sure what the problem is.
in ios 7.1, if you work with a storyboard, the scaling does what you say.
BUT, if you add a component dynamically, the animation works fine. add this to your code and check it out:

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.isExpanded = YES;


    UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 120, 40)];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(expand:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [b setTitle:@"added dynamically" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:b];

    }

    -(void)expand:(UIButton*)sender{
        CGFloat animationDuration = 0.30f; // Your duration
        CGFloat animationDelay = 0.0f; // Your delay (if any)

    if (self.isExpanded) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                              delay:animationDelay
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             [sender setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.8f, 0.8f)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.isExpanded = NO;
                         }];
    }else{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn


                    animations:^{
                         [sender setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0f, 1.0f)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.isExpanded = YES;
                     }];
}

}
```

as you said, it was fixed on ios 8. 
i thought it might have something to do with constraints, but it looks like it doesn't.

added a project that demonstrates this test here:
[the test](http://iloveandroid.co/animationForAlex.zip)

hope that helps, eiran.

Comment: works perfectly on ios 7.1 just checked:) maybe you have something else interfering with the animation.. try using the animation alone, on a new screen.

Comment: still not working on my side. I removed all the code of the CABasicAnimation in the example above, added your modification. On iOS8, it works fine, but for iOS7, animation is done from the upper left corner of the label not its centre. I tried to set the editing my question, so that you can try if you want.

Comment: ok:) i'll try in a bit. does this happen for all 7.x versions? i've tested it on 7.1

Comment: thanks ! 7.1 on the simulator. Just realising that my last sentence makes  absolutely no sense at all :D. I guess I must be tired.

Comment: ok, that explains...I do use storyboards. I suspect a weird auto layout effect, it hit me several time on when moving from iOS 7 to iOS8. Thanks a lot for you help !

Comment: np:) glad to have helped